# How would i be able to use GLU_RGBA or other GLU_ parameters?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, mingw32

hey i have yet another question. There isnt much information involved but i noticed that even though i have libglu32.a linked, and the glu.h included, im still not ablt to use `GLU_` parameters

Im wondering how that is not so. would anyone have any ideas?

if any code is needed please comment and i will respond quickly.

Also, My IDE is CodeBlocks with MinGW as the compiler on windows 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not so much an answer but a comment on your code. I see, that you're using SFML as framework. SFML internally uses OpenGL, and `sf::Image` is backed by an OpenGL texture. Or in other words: There's no need to create an OpenGL texture from a `sf::Image` on your own. Actually SFML takes care everything is properly set up for using an image as OpenGL texture.

In your code you have this:

```
GLuint LoadTexture(sf::Image image)
{
    GLuint Texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA,image.GetWidth(),image.GetHeight(), GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image.GetPixelsPtr());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    return Texture;
}
```

You don't need this function at all. All you've to do is `image->Bind()` instead of `LoadTexture(image)`, becase there is a texture already. Just take a look at the code of `sf::Image` http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/Image_8cpp-source.htm

Comment: alright, i get what youre saying, but even when doing this, the texture in the GLM model is set to that one image that is set by the material... in another of my questions, i explained that my texture was a set of vertical lines...[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436200/when-loading-textures-in-glm-the-texture-display-is-a-set-of-vertical-lines) is that question, im thinking that its the texture coords that are messed up..

Answer (score 1):

glu is not part of OpenGL. It's an auxiliary library to OpenGL, but the tokens from GLU make no sense if passed to pure OpenGL functions. Or in layman's terms: If you want to use a token beginning with `GLU_...` you've to pass it to functions prefixed `glu...`.

Comment: hm...that makes sense...i knew something was wrong with this link:[GluBuild2DMipmaps()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluBuild2DMipmaps.xml)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're getting GLU confused with GLUT.  There is *no* GLU_RGBA, but there *is* a GLUT_RGBA that's passed when creating the display window.

Comment: alright, then this link is messed up, probably outdated..[GluBuild2DMipmaps()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluBuild2DMipmaps.xml)

Comment: Ah.  For those, I think you can just use the GL_RGBA, or '4'.